# Redirecting stdout and stderr from a looping python in rc.local (at boot)

Tags: bash, boot, stderr

I want to add the following command to the `/etc/rc.local` file of my Raspberry 3:

```
python3 absolute_path_to_python_file.py &
```

The `&` is because my python program is a loop and I don't want it to prevent my Raspberry from finishing to boot.

But since I'm having some problems with this python file I would like to redirect the execution of this command to a `absolute_path_to_log_file.log`:

```
python3 absolute_path_to_python_file.py &> absolute_path_to_log_file &
```

Is this approach good?

Comment: Looks correct to me, although the man page says that (for whatever reason) `>&` is prefered over `&>`, and perhaps it would also make sense to specify for the safe side the abs path to python3. What problem are you facing with this command?

Comment: Neither of those are portable to `sh` which is what you should use in `rc.local` scripts. Try `python3 absolute_path_to_python_file.py >> absolute_path_to_log_file 2>&1 &` where we also take care to _append_ to the existing file, rather than overwrite it on each invocation.

Comment: It runs just fine but I was doing it to debug my python file which works as excepted when called from the console but doesn't for some reason when called from rc.local. It creates the log file but it is empty. When manually debugging I figured out all my imports were called but the execution was being blocked by `pickle.load(pickle_in)` ; the previous `pickle_in = open(absolute_path_to_pickle_file, "rb")` was not a problem.